# Get records with id> 60 using a ContenResolver Android

Tags: android, sms, android-contentresolver

I am developing an application that gets the messages received. I have no problem to actually receive the SMS in the app. The issue too is not how to modify data with the `ContenResolver` but to select only the envoys whose id is greater than certain value, for example greater than 60. Here is my code:

```
String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, criterio > 60, null, null);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? Show us some code and describe the problems you encountered.

Comment: The code usted is:   // List required columns
   String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };

     int criterio;
   // Get Content Resolver object, which will deal with Content
   // Provider
   ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

   // Fetch Inbox SMS Message from Built-in Content Provider
   Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, criterio > 60, null, null);
 Eclipse say me "boolean is not aplicable at ContentResolver"

Comment: Don't just post your code in the comments. Edit it in your question. I already took care of that this time.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just supply a boolean condition. You interact with the db through an SQL query. The query method may abstract this a little, but you still need to supply the condition in the SQL format. Try something like this:

```
int criterio = 60;

String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "address", "body" };
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor c = cr.query(inboxURI, reqCols, "_id > ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(criterio) } , null);
```

What happens here is that a condition is supplied `_id > ?` which means you want `_id` to be greater than some value that you specify later. And then you supply the value in the next argument in a `String` array. In this case the value of `criterio` which is`60`. You could just write `"_id > 60"` or `"_id > " + criterio` as condition, but that wouldn't be very smart. Always supply the values in the next parameter to prevent nasty things like SQL Injection.

Comment: Please don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you. That indicates to other people that my answer was helpful to you and we both get a little reputation for it.